# Alignment issue in a titlepage

Tags: titles

Here is what I am trying to achieve,

[image]

but I am getting this,

[image]

with this syntax,

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.6cm}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{24.00cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.00cm}
\parindent 0pt
\parskip 5pt
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\linespread{1.5}

\newcommand{\namelistlabel}[1]{\mbox{#1}\hfil}
\newenvironment{namelist}[1]{%1
\begin{list}{}
    {
        \let\makelabel\namelistlabel
        \settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.1\labelwidth}
    }
  }{%1
\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
  \bfseries
  \large MPhil/PhD SYNOPSIS
  \vskip.2in
  \textsc{\Large TITLE OF THE RESEARCH WORK TO BE CARRIED OUT}
 \end{center}

\vskip0.7in

%\begin{figure}[th]
 % \centering
 % \includegraphics[width=150pt]{uomlogo.PNG}
%\end{figure}

\vskip0.7in
\begin{minipage}{.40\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft}
    \bfseries\large Submitted by \par \emph{}
    \vskip.2in
    \bfseries\large Supervisor \par \emph{}
    \vskip.2in
    \bfseries\large Co-Supervisor (if Any) \par \emph{}
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hskip.2\textwidth
\begin{minipage}{.40\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft}
    \bfseries\large Name of the Scholar
    \vskip.2in
    \bfseries\large Dr./Mr. Name. \par \emph{\small Designation and Affiliation}
    \vskip.2in
    \bfseries\large Dr./Mr. Name. \par \emph{\small Designation and Affiliation}
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}

\vskip1.3in
\begin{center}
  \bfseries
  \Large Department of ....

  \Large University of .....

  \large Session 2010-2012

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}



\end{document}
```

The problem is with the alignment and the style of the text. Please suggest, how to improve this.

Comment: You have a `\vskip` between the label and where you want the name to be. This puts the name on the second line. Take the `\vskip` out. But I would format this with a tabular environment.

Comment: @AlanMunn Can you please suggest your approach as an answer?

Comment: Sorry I don't have time at the moment (hence the comment). But there are lots of problems with your code. Perhaps someone else has time to respond with more suggestion.

Comment: @AlanMunn Whenever you got some free time then please help me out.

Comment: Try using tabular options to achieve the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this way:

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.6cm}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{24.00cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.00cm}
\parindent 0pt
\parskip 5pt
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\linespread{1.5}

\newcommand{\namelistlabel}[1]{\mbox{#1}\hfil}
\newenvironment{namelist}[1]{%1
\begin{list}{}
    {
        \let\makelabel\namelistlabel
        \settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.1\labelwidth}
    }
  }{%1
\end{list}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
  \bfseries
  \large MPhil/PhD SYNOPSIS
  \vskip.2in
  \textsc{\Large TITLE OF THE RESEARCH WORK TO BE CARRIED OUT}
\end{center}

\vskip0.7in

\begin{center}% your figure here doesn't have to float, do not use figure environment
  \includegraphics[width=150pt]{example-image-a}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{}ll@{}}
    \bfseries\large Submitted by &  \bfseries\large Name of the Scholar\\[-4pt]
    & \phantom{\emph{\small Designation and Affiliation}}\\[16pt]
    \bfseries\large Supervisor & \bfseries\large Dr./Mr. Name.\\[-4pt]
    & \emph{\small Designation and Affiliation}\\[16pt]
    \bfseries\large Co-Supervisor (if Any) & \bfseries\large Dr./Mr. Name.\\[-4pt]
    & \emph{\small Designation and Affiliation}
\end{tabular*}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \bfseries\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
  \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large Department of ....\\
        \Large University of .....\\
        \large Session 2010-2012  
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\hfill \textcopyright\ 2013 All rights reserved
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*
If you want to force the title to be on one line without changing the font size, you can use `\makebox[0pt]{...}` but then it is no more aligned with the rest.

I suggest you leave it in two rows or enlarge the title page text width.

I've added `\usepackage{showframe}` only to show the alignment. Of course, you must not put it in your document.

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{article}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.6cm}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{24.00cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.00cm}
\parindent 0pt
\parskip 5pt
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\linespread{1.5}

\newcommand{\namelistlabel}[1]{\mbox{#1}\hfil}
\newenvironment{namelist}[1]{%1
\begin{list}{}
    {
        \let\makelabel\namelistlabel
        \settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.1\labelwidth}
    }
  }{%1
\end{list}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
  \bfseries
  \large MPhil/PhD SYNOPSIS
  \vskip.2in
  \makebox[0pt]{\textsc{\Large TITLE OF THE RESEARCH WORK TO BE CARRIED OUT}}
\end{center}

\vskip0.7in

\begin{center}% your figure here doesn't have to float, do not use figure environment
  \includegraphics[width=150pt]{example-image-a}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{}ll@{}}
    \bfseries\large Submitted by &  \bfseries\large Name of the Scholar\\[-4pt]
    & \phantom{\emph{\small Designation and Affiliation}}\\[16pt]
    \bfseries\large Supervisor & \bfseries\large Dr./Mr. Name.\\[-4pt]
    & \emph{\small Designation and Affiliation}\\[16pt]
    \bfseries\large Co-Supervisor (if Any) & \bfseries\large Dr./Mr. Name.\\[-4pt]
    & \emph{\small Designation and Affiliation}
\end{tabular*}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \bfseries\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
  \begin{tabular}{c}
        \Large Department of ....\\
        \Large University of .....\\
        \large Session 2010-2012  
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\hfill \textcopyright\ 2013 All rights reserved
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! One thing more, how can I add copy right symbol, i.e.," (c) 2013  All rights reserved" in the bottom of the page right side?

Comment: Once again thx. One last thing, how to force the title to be just one line without changing the size.

Comment: Thx for your valuable answer.